# Word for a video of a musical performance?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for a video of a musical performance? For example:

> There were a lot of _____ videos on his YouTube channel.

I would honestly call such videos "musical performance videos", but it sounds way too formal and I personally wouldn't use it in informal speech. There must be some kind of slang word used by Youtubers or Twitch streamers, but I am not sure what it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the word *concert*, particularly if performances were in front of a live audience:

> There were a lot of **concert** videos on his YouTube channel.

If the videos were made without the things we often associate with a concert (such as special lighting and a dancing audience), you could use this instead:

> There were a lot of **recital** videos on his YouTube channel.